# Pronunciation of the vowel "i" in Pinyin si

Tags: pronunciation

What is the pronunciation of the vowel I in Pinyin si? /ɪ/, /ɘ/ or /ɨ/ ? Each website I read describe it differently.

Please answer using IPA symbols.

Comment: Does it so matter to find a "right" symbol for a sound? I described it as [z ̩]

Comment: None of those are correct. A character like 絲 is pronounced as **/sz̩⁵⁵/**; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabic_consonant#Syllabic_fricatives - although /ɨ/ is very close.

Comment: Syllabic z ([z̩]) is popular among non-Sinologists. Sinologists often use the non-standard symbol [ɿ]. It doesn't really matter--you can pronounce it either as a syllabic fricative or as an approximant in the same place as the syllabic fricative.

Comment: @StumpyJoePete : Why would you need a non-standard symbol? Does this suggest the IPA is, in fact, deficient in achieving its supposed mission? (Not at all closed to that possibility - many "standards" leave things to be desired and dogmatism masks room for improvement.)

Comment: @The_Sympathizer IPA isn't perfect. It's my understanding that IPA only encodes differences that are contrastive in _some_ language, but (a) that's not something you can know from 1st principles, it's empirical and (b) even if it's granular enough for that purpose, there are potentially more language-specific phonetic details than that (which might be helpful for sounding like a native speaker).

Answer (score 2):

The closest is /ɨ/, at least in Taiwan where the accent is very free-flowing. In Beijing it's more like the /z/ in the comments above.

Comment: I guess you meant the [z̩] (syllabic Z), not [z].

Comment: Yep, just couldn't copy it on my phone for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually no i sound in the syllable. You can pronounce it by [s] and make it longer. The ‘i’ is just a placer, like 0 in maths.

Answer (score 1):

After *z-,c-,s-* (resp. *zh-,ch-,sh-*) pinyin *i* represents the syllabic consonant [z] (resp. [ʐ]):

> More productive are the syllabic consonants [z] and [ʐ ], which do not
> contrast with each other: [z] occurs after the dentals [ts, ts<sup>h</sup>, s], [ʐ ] after the retroflexes [ʈʂ, ʈʂ<sup>h</sup>, ʂ, ʐ ]. This is exemplified in (44).
>
> [image]
>
> Neither [z] nor [ʐ ] occurs after the palatals [tɕ, tɕh, ɕ], or after any other consonant. Some linguists, perhaps since Karlgren (1915–26), consider [z] and [ʐ ] to be ‘apical vowels’. There are three reasons.
>
> 1. There seems to be an assumption that every syllable must have a vowel—this view has been reiterated in Cheung (1986), Hsueh (1986), and Coleman (1996, 2001); secondly, some researchers argue that [z] and [ʐ ] are phonetically like a vowel. For example, Howie (1976: 10) argues that [z ] and [ʐ ] have formants, which is a property of vowels.
> 2. In addition, C. Cheng (1973: 13), citing the X-ray study of D. Zhou and Wu (1963), notes that the back of the tongue is raised in [z], similar to a vowel articulation.
> 3. Thirdly, it has been suggested that [z] and [ʐ ] are in complementary distribution with [i] and so they can be analysed as allophones of the same phoneme. Since [i] is a vowel, it is better to consider [z] and [ʐ ] to be vowels, too.

- *Phonology of Standard Chinese*, 2.9 Syllabic Consonants

Answer (score 0):

With z-,c-,s-,zh-,ch-,sh- ,it pronounces nothing, just initial consonant.